# How do I update a specific row in access using SQL update? In my current code I keep getting the error data type mismatch

Tags: vb.net

In my current code, I keep getting the error data type mismatch most of it worked before I added the SQL where statement to select a specific id

```
 Private Sub UpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click
    'tells your program the data source
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" 'refrences to the provider
    datafile = "C:\Users\Abdulaleem\Documents\Books.accdb" 'refers to the location of the file
    connectstring = provider & datafile ' combines the 2 variables
    myconnect.ConnectionString = connectstring ' this class allows you to connect to the database
    myconnect.Open() ' opens the databse
    Dim sqlupdate As String
    sqlupdate = "Update BooksTbl  set BookName='" & TitleTEXT.Text & "' , [BookAuthor]='" & AuthorTEXT.Text & "',[Genre] ='" & GenreTEXT.Text & "',[IsAvailable] = " & status & ",[DatePublished] = '" & DateTimeCHANGER.Text & "' , [PictureLocation] = '" & PiclocTEXT.Text & "' WHERE [ID] = '" & idshower.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlupdate, myconnect) 'creating new database object 
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' executes our sql query
        cmd.Dispose() 'deleting from ram to stop interferences
        myconnect.Close() 'closes database and connection
        TitleTEXT.Clear()
        AuthorTEXT.Clear()
        GenreTEXT.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception ' if the programs crashes then it will be caught here and put into the ex variable
        MsgBox(ex.Message) ' shows what error occured
        myconnect.Close()
    End Try
    myconnect.Close()
```

Comment: [IsAvailable] = " & status.ToString maybe?

Comment: Tried, didn't work. Thank you for trying

Comment: Ah ok - just a thought. What line is the error happening on?

Comment: The error happened when I added: WHERE [ID] = '" & idshower.Text & "'"

Comment: That wont happen when you use SQL Parameters instead of concatenating strings for SQL.  `WHERE [ID] = '" & idshower.Text & "'" ` forces the ID to text, ticks are not general SQL delimiters, they indicate text.  If the ID is an int/PK AI it can choke on string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your [ID] column is an integer, try changing it from:

...WHERE [ID] = '" & idshower.Text & "'"

to

...WHERE [ID] = " & idshower.Text

In access, attempting to compare a number with a string results in the message "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

Note: Unless you are certain the idshower.text actually contains a number, it'd be good practice to check this before executing the query, or access will think you're trying to use a parameter.

Also: You might want to look into parameterised queries which, although they usually result in more lines of code, protect you against things like SQL injection attacks and can perform some basic type conversion for you.

Comment: Ah - beat me to it - I was looking at the string and it looked wrong but couldn't spot where.

Comment: @AbdulaleemSaleh If this answer is satisfactory, can you mark it as accepted to close the question off?